# How to close scanner in Java in this case?

Tags: java

How to close the scanner if user input is required inside a loop? such as below:

```
public void closeScanner(){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter something:");
        String someThing = scan.nextLine();
        // some other code .....
    }
   scan.close(); //it gives warning saying unreachable code
}
```

Should I move the scanner inside the loop and close it every iteration?
or do I have to close the scanner?

Comment: Do you know what "unreachable code" means? Did you intend for this code to be unreachable?

Comment: First, you're having an infinite loop, so `close` will never be reached. Second, don't close the scanner, or else you'll close `System.in` as well

Comment: "close it every iteration?" - better not, when it is closed, `System.in`, used when it was created, will also be closed. Once `System.in` is closed it will not be re-opened and code will not be able to read anything else from it (even if creating a new `Scanner`)

Comment: I wouldn't closet that Scanner to begin with because it is connected to the standard input.

Comment: I'm also echoing all the "don't close System.in" comments.  Don't worry about System.in, it's closed automatically when the program exits.

Comment: You have to `break` out of the `while(true)` loop.  You can close the `Scanner` at the end of the application as the last line executed, but not before.

Comment: well, first, it is not an infinite loop as "some other code..." will have a break command to exit the loop. second, so we can just ignore the warning message that scanner is not closed and let it close when the program ends?

Comment: **(1)** *"it is not an infinite loop as "some other code..." will have a break command to exit the loop"*  Showing a break in the loop body should have been in the question in the first place. We shouldn't need to learn something like that in the comments.  **(2)** There may be something wrong with "some other code". If the loop is capable of executing a `break` statement, then you should not get the `unreachable code` error. In other words, the question is lacking important details.

Comment: `Scanner` is a so-called 'filter resource'. It does not itself represent a system resource that _must_ be closed, it wraps around a resource. Which may or may not be a system resource. Point is, you __only close system resources you created__. You didn't create `System.in` so you __must not__ close it. Various linter tools can't quite figure it out and will __erroneously__ tell you this resource should be closed. __This is the wrong hint__ - that is precisely the wrong thing to do. Do not close `System.in`. Do not close resources you aren't responsible for closing.

Comment: thanks for the comment @rzwitserloot. so, the question is, in my case, did I create a System.in in this command:  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @Derek No, you're not creating a new resource by referencing `System.in`.